# The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) (v9.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (10.0)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I cannot get rid of the above error message. I tried everything described in

[Xamarin forms Android project TargetFrameworkVersion Error after update to Xamarin Forms 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739914/xamarin-forms-android-project-targetframeworkversion-error-after-update-to-xamar)

, but to no avail. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

I have a Xamarin Forms 5.0 project.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 spots that need to be checked/updated

1. The version set in the Android Manifest
2. The version set in the Csproj itself

Manifest
[image: Android Manifest]
Or
[image: Direct Manifest]

Csproj
[image: Properties Csrpoj Edit]
Or
[image: Direct Csproj Edit]